# Xamarin iOS: Cannot render iOS Storyboard in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: ios, visual-studio-2013, xamarin

I cannot see the story board in Visual Studio 2013, when I open it it tells me

> There was a problem rendering this document.

Also in the errors list I have the following:

- The clocks on the Build Host and this Machine are out of Sync. Please make sure they are within 3 minutes (UTC) of each other.
- Failed to retrieve SDK status from server Xamarin.iOS Extension.

Also the output from the MAC server log tells me:

> Error sending iOS designer payload

What can be wrong here?

Comment: Have you checked that both clocks are in sync?
Is the iOS SDK (including Xcode) properly installed on the Build Host?
Can you open the Storyboard inside Xamarin Studio on the Build Host?

Comment: Hello, yes the clocks are synced, and the Storyboard renders well in Xamarin Studio on the build host machine

Comment: Visual Studio uses the Xamarin Build-host to render Storyboards. Xamarin Build-host in turn uses Xcode to render the Storyboards.
Passing back the result is apparently what's going wrong.

Do you have this problem with any storyboard? Or just this single one. If just the one, it's likely a bug or possibly a corrupted storyboard. Otherwise it might be a firewall issue of somekind or yet again a bug.

Either way I would file a bug with them and see that they have to say about it. At least you'll know whether they can reproduce the issue (if you provide them with the storyboard).

Comment: Thanks Frank, it occurred on every iOS project I created. I'll check the firewall settings and ask on Xamarin forums, I'll update you with the results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was also having a similar problem where I couldn't open the story board in Visual Studio 2012 or 2013 (I didn't have any errors in my error list, just the error when displaying the designer).  My setup is dev work in Windows 7 with Visual Studio 2012/2013 with a Mac acting as a Build Host.  I had just updated my Xamarin version from 3.0.54 to version 3.3.47 (it had been a little while) and I had created a little prototype app a couple days ago with no problems, so I figured I had killed something with the update.

In my case, the solution was checking for updates in Xamarin Studio on the Mac, where it found several that needed updated.  After installing the updates on the Mac side, I was able to display my story board in both Visual Studio 2012/2013 without issues... so I chalked it up to version mismatch issues between the Build Host and my dev environment in Windows.

Comment: In the latest build, they have added the Xamarin.iOS and Build Host version numbers to the build host window so at least this issue is something they are aware of and trying to solve.  Keeping all this stuff in sync is tricky for them, I'm sure.  I wish the rendering round trip was faster as well.  Hopefully they can improve that with time. Right now, I feel like I spend a lot of time waiting for the beach ball to stop spinning.